# Checking for viewable items in a Flatlist and passing a prop if the item being rendered id matches a viewable items id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video

So basically what I said in the title, I am simply trying to change a prop that im passing to the component of Post if the item currently being rendered is in the viewport.
I am getting double the output like its firing twice, and its not even correct.
im comparing a key to the id (same thing) and if the 'activeVideo !== item.id' (video id's) are the same
the video should play, because i pass 'False' to the 'paused' property.
question is why am i getting double the output and why are both videos being paused when one of them clearly shouldnt>?
Need help fast, its for a school project.

Home.js

```
const [activeVideo, setActiveVideo] = useState(null);
const onViewRef = React.useRef((viewableItems)=> {
    setActiveVideo(viewableItems.changed[0].key)
})
const viewConfigRef = React.useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 75 })

return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            data={posts}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').height - 24}
            snapToAlignment={'start'}
            decelerationRate={'fast'}
            onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
            viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Post 
            post={item}
            paused={activeVideo !== item.id}
            />}
        />
    </View>
)}
```

Post.js

```
const Post = (props) => {
const [post, setPost] = useState(props.post);
const [paused, setPaused] = useState(props.paused);
console.log(props.paused)

const onPlayPausePress = () => {
  setPaused(!paused);
};
const onPlayPausePress2 = () => {
    setPaused(!paused);
};
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <Image
            source={{uri: post.poster}}
            style={styles.video2}
            />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPlayPausePress}>
                <Video
                source={post.postUrl}
                style={styles.video}
                onError={(e)=> console.log(e)}
                resizeMode={'cover'}
                repeat
                paused={paused}
                />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
)}
```